# How can I unit / integration test Mobile Services Client sync operations?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to figure out how I can test my Push/Pull/Sync logic and validate that the server side service is working properly.

I have a xamarin.forms app that uses azure mobile services. Ideally I would like to have some integration tests where I can create an object on the client and then trigger a push/sync to the service side, then assert that the data was entered into the database correctly.

Is this possible or what is the strategy for this type of testing be it unit or integration. I'm just not sure where to begin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In our own codebase, we mainly do unit testing for offline scenarios. What you're describing sounds like integration testing.

- The SDK unit tests are here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/tree/master/sdk/test
- Integration tests: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/tree/master/e2etest